# Which mode is a cantilever oscillating at when twanged at one side and changing the length?

Tags: experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator, elasticity

so I am measuring the relationship between the period and length of a cantilever beam, and I came across a huge roadblock. Apparently the relationship is [image: Beam]

but I don't understand what the mode has to do with it. Is the mode just 1 if I twang it at one end? Also can someone tell me why the length affects the frequency? Thanks guys so much, I can't find answers anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you just twang it at one end, you will excite several modes simultaneously. Note that for a cantilever, the frequencies of the modes are *not* nice multiples of each other, as they are for a stretched string!

However you will *mainly* excite the lowest mode, and the higher frequency modes will be damped out faster. That is probably "near enough" for a lab experiment.

If you really need to excite just one mode, you need a different experimental method - for example, use a signal generator and a force transducer to apply a sinusoidal force to the cantilever, and adjust the frequency to give the maximum amplitude of response.

The frequency of any vibrating object is proportional to $\sqrt{k/m}$, where $k$ and $m$ measure the stiffness and mass. For a cantilever of length $l$, $k$ is proportional to $1/l^3$ and $m$ is proportional to $l$, so $\sqrt{k/m}$ is proportional to $1/l^2$.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. Do you have a link or anything that can explain this, as I need to cite my sources. Please reply quick as I do not have much time. Thanks again.

Comment: See any textbook or web site on multi-degree-of-freedom (MDOF) dynamics for the general theory.  The links in the other comment have derivations for the vibration of a cantilever beam.